# What does the 2nd parameter in Node Crypto .createHmac() do?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, hmac

Documentation says it "signs" the data, but what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

It is the shared secret key used to generate the HMAC (keyed-hash MAC HMAC) tag for the data. The tag will be sent along with the data. The receiver can verify the the authenticity and integrity of the data it receives by validating the associated HMAC tag/sign using shared secret key.